# Vim put command not allowing double quotes (and therefore no escape sequences)

Tags: vim

I'm trying to run a script containing the Vim put command.  I want a tab character in my string.  The following code works, but the '\t' isn't interpreted due to the single quotes.  When I replace the string with double quotes, the error messages seem to suggest that the first double quote ended the command.
Code is...

```
let a=range(0,5)
for i in a
    put=i . '\t' . printf('\t%c', i)
endfor
```

Output is...

```
0\t\t
1\t\t
2\t\t
3\t\t
4\t\t
5\t\t
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I want the '\t' replaced with an actual tab character.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of a literal string.

```
let a=range(0,5)
for i in a
    put=i . \"\t\" . printf(\"\t%c\", i)
endfor
```

You can also use `map()` to shorten this up quite a bit:

```
put=map(range(5), 'printf(\"%d\t\t%c\", v:val, v:val)')
```

For more help see: `:h string` and `:h literal-string`

Comment: Have you checked the output?  It doesn't work on my Vim 7.4.

Comment: Ok, it works now that you have edited your response and escaped the double quotes.  I thought you only escaped quotes inside strings and didn't try this.

Comment: @Mikey Quoting is needed because `"` is taken as the start of a comment otherwise.